# How to connect to MySQL container on Docker using Spring Boot project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to run a Spring Boot application where db has to be connected to a MySQL container on Docker. I used following code and commands.

Application properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/practice
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=CVnit1234!
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.sql.init.platform=mysql
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Commands used for creating container & running it on Docker:

Pulling mysql image from Docker Hub:

```
docker pull mysql
```

Creating a container:

```
docker run --name mysqldb --network spring-net -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password MYSQL_DATABASE=practice -d mysql:latest
```

After this command, a container is created and even it is up and working fine. I was able to login to sql bash and execute some queries.

I tried with multiple jdbc urls:

- jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/practice
- jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3307/practice
- jdbc:mysql://mysqldb/practice
- jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/practice
- jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3307/practice

None of this worked, but I was able to connect to `localhost:3306` and `localhost:3307`.

Below is my spring boot code. When I am trying to connect through the Spring Boot application, I was getting the following error.

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException:Communication link failure

The problem over here is when I am trying to connect to localhost the application is up and working, but when trying to connect to mysql container, I was not able to connect.

Comment: Ifyou are on your localhost use `localhost` not `mysqldb`. The latter is only needed if yuo are running from within docker in the same network.

Comment: Your expectation that you should be able to use hostname `mysqldb` when your Spring Boot application is running on the host (instead of in Docker) is wrong. When the application is running on the host, you have to use `localhost:3307`. If your Spring Boot application was running on Docker (in the same network), then using `mysqldb:3306` would have worked.

Comment: Is the application running inside a container, outside a container on the same host, or on a different host entirely?  (In all three of these cases the program is running "on localhost" but it means something different.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your network to ensure that the application network is connected to the MySQL network